# No Data Returned in Query with Equal Predicate on a CHAR Type Column

Tags: oracle, jdbc, char, prepared-statement, resultset

This is my code and i have a column which is named as Product Id and data type as CHAR (6 byte) in oracle. I have used set string method for this column to retrieve the details from Database. Actually i got result set as false (It has empty) and there is no records fetched. But when am using 'PRODUCT_ID="+value+"' it works. How to fix this..

```
sSQL="SELECT * FROM CART_VIEW WHERE PRODUCT_ID=? AND  PRODUCT_NAME=? ";
ps=conn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
ps.setString(++i, sProductId);
ps.setString(++i, sProductName);
rs=ps.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column format CHAR(6) means (contrary to the VARCHAR2 format) that the strings shorter than 6 bytes are blank padded. I.e. you must provide the string with added trailing blanks to the exact length of the column.

Example if you insert 'X' in the column `XX CHAR(6)`

```
 -- returns nothing
 select * from test where xx = 'X'; 

 -- returns a row
 select * from test where xx = 'X     ';
```

I.e. you must pass in setString the full length string.

Comment: It works Bomber. Also your explanation helps to understood the concept

Comment: @muthu you are welcome!  Generally if you have a variable length keys, the usual format is VARCHAR2 (even to avoid this problem with padding).